# Find and delete after 1st occurance of empty row in csv with python

Tags: python, csv

I'd like to delete all rows after the 1st occurrence of an empty row.

1. What is the best way to read down rows until encountering an empty row?
2. what is the best command for deleting all proceeding rows?

Comment: By typing code. (What have you tried? Where is your code so far?)

Comment: If you don't give us any code to work with, how can we give you any to use?

Comment: There are a few ways you could do this, if the file is not too large I would suggest reading all of the data into  a variable, closing the file and then writing to the same filename line by line while the line is not empty then bow large is the file you need to process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script that you could use. The code in the main function is just to allow you to select a file (or pick this up as a command line argument if given). This then calls the crop_file function which does what you described in the question by opening the file, reading the data up to the first empty line into memory, closing the file and then writing the stored data to the same file if you confirm that you want the remaining lines deleted.

Let me know if you have any questions about the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, csv, sys, Tkinter, tkFileDialog as fd

# stop tinker shell from opening as only needed for file dialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

def crop_file(in_path):
    # read file into memory
    file_obj = open(in_path, 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter='\t')
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        if not row or not any(row):
            break #stop at empty row
        else:
            data.append(row)
    file_obj.close()

    print 'Found', len(data), 'rows of data without empty lines.'
    conf = raw_input('delete remaining lines? (Y|N): ').upper()[0]

    if conf == 'Y':
        # write data to file
        file_obj = open(in_path, 'wb')
        writer = csv.writer(file_obj)
        writer.writerows(data)
        file_obj.close

def main():
    in_path = None
    prog_name = sys.argv[0]

    # check if in_path are inlcuded as cmd line args...
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        in_path = sys.argv[1]
        if not os.path.exists(in_path):
            print 'Usage:', prog_name, '[file_path>]'
            print 'cannot find the file provided for file_path:\n', in_path
            sys.exit("Error - invalid excel_file_path arg")
    else:
        try:
            # set current working directory to user's my documents folder
            os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getenv('userprofile'),'documents'))
        except:
            pass

    # ask user for path to file...
    while not in_path:
        print "Please select the file to read data from ..."
        try:
            in_path = fd.askopenfilename()
        except:
            print 'Error selecting file.'
        if not in_path:
            cont = raw_input('Do you want to continue? (Y|N): ').upper()[0]
            if cont == 'N':
                sys.exit("Error - unable to select input file")

    crop_file(in_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This code recognizes that I have 33 rows with entries, but in my .csv there are actually 26 rows, then 3 blank rows, then 5 rows of data at the end (these are the rows to be deleted.) How might I alter this so that it selects just the first 26 rows and deletes the rest?

Comment: @gigawatts This is what it was doing for the test data that I checked it against. Can you post your data somewhere like hastebin and send me a link then I will try it against your data and make the amendments needed (obviously if there are any personal details etc. you should make the data anonymous first).

Comment: @gigawatts I suspect this is a subtle different in the empty lines between my test file and yours. Are your blank lines literally empty or do they contain spaces etc.?

Comment: I really appreciate the help, as I am very new to Python. I put my slight tweaks to your original code in the edit to my original post...

Comment: @gigawatts glad you got there in the end. I have updated the post above with the changes you made.